# Как завтавить работать scanf() в VS2012

Tags: visual-studio, c++, visual-studio-2012

Здравствуйте!

MSVS 2012 не хочет работать с базовой сишной функцией scanf(), нужно писать scanf_s().
Проект консольный, пустой. Как заставить её работать?

PS `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` не помогло.

Спасибо.

Comment: Метод, описанный в ответе, так же **работает и для MCVS 2013**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
#define  _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS  тут не поможет.
```

Вам нужно сделать вот что ( работает в Visual Studio 2012, думаю, сработает и в более ранних)

1. Пункт меню View => Other Windows => Property Manager
2. В появившемся окне  кликаете правой кнопкой по проекту, выбираете пункт Properties
3. Configuration Properties => C/C++ => Preprocessor => Preprocessor Definitions
4. Кликаете Edit в выпадающем списке
5. Добавляете в появившемся окошке строку _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
6. Сохраняете, закрываете. Должно работать

Для наглядности:

** Как найти Property Manager**
[image]

**Вариант 2. На русской VS может не сработать**
В правом верхнем углу есть поле для поиска:
[image]

**Куда тыкать дальше**
[image]

**И наконец**

[image]

Comment: У меня vs на русском.

Comment: ну неужели не сориентируетесь?

Comment: не могу Property Manager найти.

Comment: щас подождите скриншоты выложу

Comment: Заработало, спасибо.
А можно от этой фигни в vs 2012 вообще избавится?

Comment: >А можно от этой фигни в vs 2012 вообще избавится?

Не очень понял, вы о чем?

Comment: Для каждого проекта, что бы не делать эту манипуляцию. У меня лично, в vs 2010 всё нормально работало, а в 12 нет.

Comment: Можно также написать в начале программы #pragma warning(disable:<числовой код предупреждения>)